# Maclaurin expansion of $\arcsin x$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the first five terms of the Maclaurin expansion of $\arcsin x$, possibly using the fact that

$$\arcsin x = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^{1/2}}.$$

I can only see that I can interchange differentiation and integration but not sure how to go about this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to expand the *integral*? The integrand is the part we know how to expand from the binomial theorem, not with this integral.

Comment: term by term integration

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I was doing this I would start with one of the very common series like $\sin(x)$, $e^x$, etc. and then use substitution. The one that fits best here in my opinion is:
 $$
\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{x^3}{16} - \frac{5x^4}{128} + \dotsc
$$
Through substitution, we can obtain:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{3x^4}{8} + \frac{5x^6}{16} + \frac{35x^8}{128} + \dotsc
$$
Then by integration:
$$
\arcsin(x) = \int^x_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt = x + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{3x^5}{40} + \frac{5x^7}{112} + \frac{35x^9}{1152} + \dotsc
$$

Comment: What is this substitution?

Comment: I think the substitution is $x=\dfrac{y^2}{1-y^2}$.

Comment: What substitution are you talking about @Daniel Fischer

Comment: @324 I'm not sure what noahklein had in mind. Possibly to replace $x$ with $-x^2$ in the series for $\sqrt{1+x}$, and then use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-x^2} = (1 + x^2 + x^4 + \ldots)\sqrt{1-x^2}$. But I'd rather go with Norbert's or Sasha's answer.

Comment: Another approach would be to differentiate the series for $\sqrt{1+x}$, then substitute $-x^2$ for $x$.

Answer (score 22):

**Hint:**
Use the following [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)
$$
(1+z)^\alpha=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\ldots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}z^k
$$
with $z=-t^2$, $\alpha=-1/2$. Then integrate.

Answer (score 20):

Change variables $t = x u$:
$$
   \arcsin(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{ x}{(1- x^2 u^2)^{1/2}} \mathrm{d} u
$$
Now using Taylor series expansion of the integrand:
$$
  \frac{ x}{(1- x^2 u^2)^{1/2}} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n} x^{2n+1} u^{2n} 
$$
Integrating term-wise:
$$
  \arcsin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1 }{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n} \frac{ x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$$

Answer (score 7):

As has been mentioned in other answers, the series for $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is most easily found by substituting $x^2$ into the series for $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}$. But for fun we can also derive it directly by differentiation.

To find $\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ at $x=0$, note that any factors of $x$ in the numerator produced by differentiating the denominator must be differentiated by some later differentiation for the term to contribute at $x=0$. Thus the number of contributions is the number of ways to group the $n$ differential operators into pairs, with the first member of each pair being applied to the numerator and the second member being applied to the factor $x$ produced by the first. This number is non-zero only for even $n=2k$, and in that case it is $\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}$. Each such pair accumulates another factor $1\cdot3\cdot\cdots\cdot(2k-1)=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}$ from the exponents in the denominator. Thus the value of the $n$-th derivative at $x=0$ is $\frac{(2k)!^2}{4^k(k!)^2}$, so the Maclaurin series is

$$
\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k)!}\frac{(2k)!^2}{4^kk!}x^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k}{4^k}x^{2k}\;.
$$

Then integrating yields

$$
\arcsin x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k}{4^k(2k+1)}x^{2k+1}\;.
$$

Answer (score 6):

The following Python + [SymPy](http://sympy.org) script:

```
from sympy import *

# symbolic variable
x = Symbol('x')

# compute and print Maclaurin series
print series(asin(x),x,0,11,'+')
```

produces the following output:

```
x + x**3/6 + 3*x**5/40 + 5*x**7/112 + 35*x**9/1152 + O(x**11)
```

Therefore, assuming that the implementation is correct, the answer to your question is:

$$\displaystyle\arcsin(x) \approx x + \frac{1}{6} x^3 + \frac{3}{40} x^5 + \frac{5}{112} x^7 + \frac{35}{1152} x^9$$

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is the terms of $\arcsin x$ out to $x^5$, it’s also easy enough to invert (“revert”) the series $x-x^3/6+x^5/120$ by hand. You’re looking for a series $A(x)=x + ax^3+bx^5$ so that $\sin(A(x))=x$, but you’re willing to do it modulo terms of degree six or more. Just working modulo $(x^4)$, you see immediately that $a=+1/6$, so the only work is to find $b$. When you calculate $\sin(A(x))$ out to degree five, always ignoring any term in $x^n$ for $n>5$, you get $x+(b-1/12+1/120)x^5$, and you want that last part to be zero, so $b=3/40$.

Answer (score 5):

Considering the binomial expansion
\begin{align}
\frac 1{\sqrt{1-u}}&=1+\frac12 u+\frac12\cdot\frac32\frac{u^2}{2!}+\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac52\frac{u^3}{3!}++\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac52\cdot\frac 72\frac{u^4}{4!}+\dotsm \\
&=1+\frac12 u+\frac{1\cdot3}{2^2\,2!}u^2 +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot 5}{2^3\,3!}u^3 + +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{2^4\,4!}u^4\dotsm ,
\end{align}
and substituting $u=x^2$, then integrating term by term, you obtain
\begin{align}
\arcsin x&= x+ \frac12 \frac{x^3}3+\frac{1\cdot3}{2^2\,2!}\frac{x^5}5 +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot 5}{2^3\,3!}\frac{x^7}7 + +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{2^4\,4!}\frac{x^9}9+\dotsm \\[1ex]
&=x+ \frac12 \frac{x^3}3+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot 4}\frac{x^5}5 +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot 5}{2\cdot4\cdot 6}\frac{x^7}7 +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8}\frac{x^9}9+\dotsm \\[1ex]
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Recall the series
$$(1-x)^{-a}=\,_1F_0(a;;x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(a)_n}{n!}x^n$$
where $(s)_n=\frac{\Gamma(s+n)}{\Gamma(s)}=(s+n-1)(s+n-2)\cdots s$. Hence
$$\begin{align}
\arcsin z&=\int_0^z \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\\
&=\int_0^z\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_n}{n!}t^{2n}dt\\
&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_n}{n!}\int_0^z t^{2n}dt\\
&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_n}{n!}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.
\end{align}$$