# Rewriting an expression derived from arcsinx

Tags: calculus

This is in regards to another question on here, [Maclaurin expansion of $\arcsin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/maclaurin-expansion-of-arcsin-x)

In the solution accepted by the OP, the expression

$\sqrt {1-x}$

is rewritten "using substitution" as

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

I don't see how this is done?

Comment: Pray, provide some details!! What don't you see about it? Do you know what substitution is? Can you see that $x=t^2 $ is a valid substitution? If not, why do you think it's wrong? If yes, that's exactly what's done there, only with a slightly different notation, $x$ substituted to $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the OP is simply referring to [**binomial expansion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$(1 + x)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \; {\alpha \choose k} \; x^k   = 1 + \alpha x + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!} x^2 + \cdots$$

with $\alpha =-\frac12$ and $x=y^2$ which leads to

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = 1 + \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{3y^4}{8} + \frac{5y^6}{16} + \frac{35y^8}{128} + \dotsc
$$

Answer (score 0):

The OP uses:
$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{x^3}{16} - \frac{5x^4}{128} + \dotsc$$
to get:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{3x^4}{8} + \frac{5x^6}{16} + \frac{35x^8}{128} + \dotsc$$
$===================================$

First, substitute $x=-x^2$ to get:
$$\sqrt{1-x^2} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{8} - \frac{x^6}{16} - \frac{5x^8}{128} - \dotsc$$
Second, consider its reciprocal:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{8} - \frac{x^6}{16} - \frac{5x^8}{128} - \dotsc}=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots \Rightarrow \\
(1 - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{8} - \frac{x^6}{16} - \frac{5x^8}{128} - \dotsc)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots)=1 \Rightarrow \\
\begin{align}a_0&=1;\\
a_1&=0;\\
a_2-\frac{a_0}{2}=0 \Rightarrow a_2&=\frac12;\\
a_3-\frac{a_1}{2}=0 \Rightarrow a_3&=0;\\
a_4-\frac{a_2}{2}-\frac{a_0}{8}=0 \Rightarrow a_4&=\frac38;\\
a_5-\frac{a_3}{2}-\frac{a_1}{8}=0 \Rightarrow a_5&=0;\\
a_6-\frac{a_4}{2}-\frac{a_2}{8}-\frac{a_0}{16}=0 \Rightarrow a_6&=\frac{5}{16};\\
\vdots
\end{align}$$