# How to calculate inverse sine without a calculator?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to be able to be able to do this on paper without help from a calculator and I’m a complete beginner. If you can, please explain in the simplest terms without excluding any math or detail.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good way to calculate it - you might do best by "calculate a table of values of $\sin$ and look for where the desired value occurs" - and then perhaps using root finding methods to improve your approximation. I'm sure they made tables of this back in the day, but I bet it was a lot of work - but maybe someone else knows a better answer!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/maclaurin-expansion-of-arcsin-x

Comment: When you say you want to calculate arcsin, could you tell us how you calculate the sine?

Comment: I don’t know how to do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an infinite expansion for $\sin^{-1}x$ that you could do by hand which goes as-
$$\sin^{-1}x= x + \frac 1 2 \frac {x^3} 3 + \frac {1\cdot 3} {2 \cdot 4} \frac {x^5} 5 + \frac {1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} {2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6} \frac {x^7} 7 + \cdots$$
Ofcourse, the answer will not be exact but calculating the first three terms should be sufficient.

Comment: Is there a name for this method so that I can look up more on this?

Comment: It's not really a method. This is known as a [Taylor Series Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) and is used to represent non-algebraic functions (such as $\sin^{-1} x$) as an infinite sum in polynomial form.