# The Derivatives of $\ln(\arcsin(x^4) + \cos(x))$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) =  \ln(\arcsin(x^4) + \cos(x))$.  Find $f^{(k)}(0)$ for $k=1,2,3,4$.

This is from my son's university calculus quiz which is already finished.  He challenged me and I could not come up with a good solution.  My son gave me a hint to make use of Taylor theorem though....

The original problem is $\arcsin(x^6)$ instead of $\arcsin(x^4)$ and to derive up to $k=6$, so directly differentiating 6 times with chain rule is not the expected answer.

Comment: It would be better if you post context _e.g._ the source of the problem, what you have tried, etc. (You can click on the edit button below the post to do so!) Otherwise the post will attract downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have just updated the question.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. Are you a math major? (Don't disclose if you don't want to, just a casual question)

Comment: @ultralegend5385 No, I’m just an old man who majored Economics nearly thirty years ago.  My son has just come home for summer vacation and challenged me if I could solve his first year calculus class quiz. I didn’t know the application of the Taylor series other than approximations so everybody’s answers really helped me to acquire the alternative usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, this question just requires one to know a 'trick'

$$f(x) = \ln \left[ \arcsin(x^4) + \cos(x) \right]$$

We see that when $x=0$, the function inside log becomes a one, now we can manipulate the above as:

$$ f(x) = \ln \left[ 1+ \underbrace{[ \cos x + \arcsin(x^4) - 1 ]}\right]=\left[ \cos x  + \arcsin(x^4) - 1 \right] - \frac{1}{2} \left[ \cos x  + \arcsin(x^4) - 1 \right]^2...$$

Notice that the underbraced term is some small quantity in $h$ , near zero , so I applied the $\log(1+x)$ expansion. Now, consider the maclaurain of the quantity:

$$ g(x) = \cos(x) + \arcsin(x^4)-1$$

We can expand the above expansion from the standard expansions till the fourth order:

$$ g(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2!} + x^4( 1 + \frac{1}{4!}) +O(x^5)$$

Upon substitution into $f(x)$ we find,

$$ f(x) = - \left[ \frac{x^2}{2!} - x^4 (1 + \frac{1}{4!})\right]- \left[\frac12 \frac{x^4}{2!^2}\right] + O(x^6)$$

Now what you gotta do is, compare the coefficients of the powers in $x$ with the standard maclaurin coefficient for $f$, i.e: for $x^k$, it is $\frac{d^k f(x)}{dx^k}|_0 \frac{1}{k!}$

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanations!  I finally understand everyone's answers!

Comment: Always feels good to be appreciated! Thank you for the kind comment @waterloos

Answer (score 2):

Using your hint: express $f(x)$ as a Maclaurin series.

We have the well known series:

$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!}+ \frac{x^8}{8!} - \cdots$$

$$\arcsin x = x +\frac{x^3}{6} +\frac{3}{40}x^5 + \frac{5}{112}x^7 + \frac{35}{1152} x^9 + \cdots$$
Ref:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html

$$\ln (1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^5}{5} + \cdots$$

Carefully combining the above:

$$f(x) =  \ln(\arcsin(x^4) + \cos(x))= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!} x^k =\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k= -\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{11}{12} x^4 + \frac{43}{90}x^6 + O(x^8).$$

You can now read off the values from this series:

$$f^{(k)}(0) = k! a_k$$

So

$$\left\{f(0),f^\prime(0), f^{\prime \prime}(0), \cdots, f^{(6)}(0) \right\} = \left\{0,0,-1,0,22,0,344 \right\}$$

Comment: How did you find $a_k$?  The students in his class are not supposed to use calculators nor computers.

Comment: Updated the answer to include some motivation for computing this series.

Comment: The coefficient on $x^4$ is wrong. It’s $11/12$, not $11/22$.

Comment: I chose @Buraian's answer b/c I could finally understand the logic behind the lines in your answer.  Thank you for your immediate help!

Comment: @symplectomorphic, Thank you, corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy is to use substitutions into Maclaurin series. Here’s a compressed hint. (Note you can do all this in your head so long as you know all the basic series. If not, you might just need paper for the arcsine series.)

Write the argument of the logarithm as $1+(\arcsin(x^4)+\cos(x)-1)$ in order to pattern match with $\ln(1+x).$

Now use the Maclaurin expansions for arcsine (e.g. using [Maclaurin expansion of $\arcsin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/maclaurin-expansion-of-arcsin-x) if it’s unknown in advance) and cosine to get $1+(x^4-x^2/2+x^4/24)$ up to order 4.

Finally, substitute into the first two terms of the Maclaurin for $\ln(1+x)$ to get $-x^2/2+11x^4/12$ up to order 4. (You need the first two terms because squaring the $x^2/2$ factor gives another order 4 contribution.)

From here you read off the derivatives.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to give me how to approach this problem.  Your strategy with @Buraian's explanations made me understood the motivation behind this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an alternative approach, it suffices to differentiate $f(x)$ *once* and then approximate things up to *cubics* in $x$ (since we're only taking three more derivatives). Using "$\approx$" to indicate we're ignoring powers of $x$ greater than $3$, we find

$$f'(x)={4x^3\left(1\over\sqrt{1-x^8}\right)-\sin x\over\arcsin(x^4)+\cos x}\approx{4x^3-\left(x-{1\over6}x^3 \right)\over1-{1\over2}x^2}\approx\left({25\over6}x^3-x\right)\left(1+{1\over2}x^2 \right)\approx-x+{11\over3}x^3$$

and thus $f''(x)\approx-1+11x^2$, $f'''(x)\approx22x$, and $f^{(4)}\approx22$, so we get $f'(0)=0$, $f''(0)=-1$, $f'''(0)=0$, and $f^{(4)}(0)=22$.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing the interesting method!  It took me a couple of days since I am not so proficient in math.  But I learn another technique to apply Taylor series and I am happy.  Thank you Barry!