# Special sum to show by hand : $S<e$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, summation

Problem :

Show that :

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{104}\arcsin\left(\frac{2}{n^2+1}\right)<e$$

Without a computer (by hand).

This problem seems very difficult.

To show it I have used Jordan's inequality :

Let $0<x<1$ then we have :

$$\pi/2x>\arcsin(x)$$

But it's too far.Hopefully we can truncate the series .

We have the inequality :

Let $x>11$ then we have :

$$g(x)=\arcsin\left(2/(x^2+1)\right)<f(x)=2/x^2+2/(1-x^4)+1/32*1/x^4$$

Then with a computer we have :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10}g(n)+\sum_{n=11}^{104}f(n)<e$$

Then we can use :

$\exists m>0$ large enought such that :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}1/i^2<\pi^2/6-1/m+0.5*1/m^2\tag{I}$$

Better approach :

Using $0<x<1$ :

$$\operatorname{arctanh}(x)>\arcsin(x)$$

And cutting the series it telescopes.

We can improves it with for $0<x<1$:

$$(\operatorname{arctanh
}(x))/2+x/2>\arcsin(x)$$

Cutting and use $I$.

How to show by hand?

Comment: $S_{104} \approx e - 0.000004$ and $S_{105} \approx e + 0.0002$. What makes you think that this can be shown by hand?

Comment: One can take an almost arbitrary series and determine the largest partial sum which is less than $e$, $\pi$, or whatever. What makes this problem interesting?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/maclaurin-expansion-of-arcsin-x

Comment: @BobDobbs Thanks you.@MartinR When i saw your question i was thinking to Isaac Asimov...

Comment: @ErikSatie [This approximation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282+%28601+%2B+1162+n%5E2+%2B+2121+n%5E4+%2B+2380+n%5E6+%2B+1645+n%5E8+%2B+630+n%5E10+%2B+105+n%5E12%29%29%2F%28105+%281+%2B+n%5E2%29%5E7%29%2Casin%282%2F%28n%5E2%2B1%29%29) is [less than](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sgn%28asin%282%2F%28n%5E2%2B1%29%29-%282+%28601+%2B+1162+n%5E2+%2B+2121+n%5E4+%2B+2380+n%5E6+%2B+1645+n%5E8+%2B+630+n%5E10+%2B+105+n%5E12%29%29%2F%28105+%281+%2B+n%5E2%29%5E7%29%29) the summand. Maybe it helps?

Comment: Well by hand it's too large can you show $I$    ? Thanks for the attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Remarks*: Recently, I learned the method of bounding the series by using telescoping series. Perhaps we may find telescoping series better than (2) and (5).

**Some thoughts**:

It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arcsin\frac{2}{n^2 + 1}
< \mathrm{e} + \sum_{n=105}^\infty \arcsin\frac{2}{n^2 + 1}. \tag{1}$$

Using
$$\arcsin\frac{2}{n^2 + 1}
> \frac{2}{n - \frac{12}{25}} - \frac{2}{n + 1 - \frac{12}{25}}, \quad \forall n \ge 105, \tag{2}$$
(easy to prove by taking derivative)
we have
$$ \sum_{n=105}^\infty \arcsin\frac{2}{n^2 + 1}
> \sum_{n=105}^\infty
\left(\frac{2}{n - \frac{12}{25}} - \frac{2}{n + 1 - \frac{12}{25}}\right) = \frac{2}{105 - \frac{12}{25}} = \frac{50}{2613}. \tag{3}$$

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arcsin\frac{2}{n^2 + 1}
< \mathrm{e} + \frac{50}{2613}. \tag{4}$$

We have, for all $n \ge 7$,
\begin{align*}
 \arcsin\frac{2}{n^2 + 1}
 < g(n) &:= 2\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1}\right) 
 + \left(\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}\right)\\
 &\qquad 
 - \frac13 \left(\frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^3}\right)
 - \left(\frac{1}{n^4} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^4}\right)\\
 &\qquad - \frac{1}{15}\left(\frac{1}{n^5} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^5}\right)
 + \frac53\left(\frac{1}{n^6} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^6}\right)\\
 &\qquad + \frac{25}{21}\left(\frac{1}{n^7} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^7}\right). \tag{5}
\end{align*}
(It can be proved by taking derivative. The proof is quite complicated by hand.)

Using (5), we have
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin\frac{2}{n^2 + 1}\\
 <{}&\sum_{n=1}^{6} \arcsin\frac{2}{n^2 + 1}
 + \sum_{n=7}^{\infty} g(n)\\
 ={}& \frac{\pi}{2} + \arcsin\frac25 + \arcsin\frac15 + \arcsin\frac{2}{17} + \arcsin\frac{1}{13} + \arcsin\frac{2}{37}\\ 
 &\quad + 2\left(\frac{1}{7} \right) 
 + \left(\frac{1}{7^2}\right)
 - \frac13 \left(\frac{1}{7^3} \right)
 - \left(\frac{1}{7^4} \right)- \frac{1}{15}\left(\frac{1}{7^5}\right)
 + \frac53\left(\frac{1}{7^6} \right) + \frac{25}{21}\left(\frac{1}{7^7} \right)\\
 <{}& \mathrm{e} + \frac{50}{2613}.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: Did very the last inequality “by hand” without the use of a computer?

Comment: @MartinR I call it 'some thoughts' rather than "answer" because it is not easy to do it by hand.

Comment: @MartinR If we can find a rational function $f(x)$ such that $\arcsin \frac{2}{n^2 + 1} < f(n) - f(n+1)$ for all $n \ge 1$, it is better. In (5), we need more terms than now ($n\ge 7$).

Comment: Can you do something with my new work ?

Comment: @ErikSatie I am not following your writing. Actually, I am not quite interested in such things (e.g. by hand; as Martin R pointed out "One can take an almost arbitrary series and determine the largest partial sum which is less than e, π, or whatever."