# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arcsin x}{x}=1$

Tags: inverse

I am trying to show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\arcsin x}{x}=1$$ I am new to inverse trigonometric functions, so I am sorry if it's obvious.

So if we put $\arcsin x=t,$ then $\sin t=x$. How do I say where t goes when $x\to 0$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the limit involving $\frac {\sin x}x$ where $x\to 0$?

Comment: @abiessu, yes, I'm. After we change the variable we have that the givin limit is equal to $\lim_{t\to}\dfrac{t}{\sin t}$, but I am not sure whut number $t$ approaches in the new limit as $x\to 0$. That's my question.

Comment: Take it in reverse; if $t\to 0$ then what value does $\sin t$ go to?

Comment: to $0.$........................................

Comment: The typical assumption is that $\sin^{-1}x$ gives values in the interval $[-\frac {\pi}2,\frac {\pi}2]$.  Otherwise the original limit could not exist.

Comment: To understand why $t\to\arcsin0$, it's a worthwhile exercise to do this through the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit, by relating it to the same definition of $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{\sin t}$.

Comment: Alternative approach is to obtain the Taylor series for the arcsin function.  See, for example, the answer of noahklein in [this MathSE article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/maclaurin-expansion-of-arcsin-x).

Comment: A less fiddly version of @user2661923's suggestion is 
L'Hôpital's rule.